# Combining lists of strings in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have two lists of strings in Ansible:

```
vars:
  pre:
    - one
    - two
  post:
    - alpha
    - beta
```

I can get the cartesian product of these lists easily:

```
set_fact: prods="{{pre|product(post)|list}}"
```

How do I then combine the individual parts to get a list like this:

```
prods:
  - one-alpha
  - one-beta
  - two-alpha
  - two-beta
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a loop!

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    pre:
      - one
      - two
    post:
      - alpha
      - beta

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        prods: "{{ prods|default([]) + ['{}-{}'.format(item.0, item.1)] }}"
      loop: "{{ pre|product(post)|list }}"

    - debug:
        var: prods
```

This will produce as output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "prods": [
        "one-alpha", 
        "one-beta", 
        "two-alpha", 
        "two-beta"
    ]
}
```